# Incremental rolling function on nested lists

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am still a beginner in python, and tried to convert this code that I wrote in Java into Python

```java
// shifts the element  of each row according to the row's index and the element's
// index in the row example row 0  no shifts ( since all the elements would get 
// their original positions from this formula [(i+j) % d] row 1, one shift for all
// the elements, and so on for all the rows in the array using the same formula

public void doSomething(int[][] a) {
    int[] temp = new int[d];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            temp[j] = a[i][(j + i) % a[i].length];
        }
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, a[i], 0, a[i].length);
    }
}
```

I tried something like:

```py
def do_something(self, arr):
    temp_list = []
    i = 0
    for row in arr:
        j = 0
        for _ in row:
            y = (i + j) % self.d
            z = arr[i, y]
            temp_list.append(z)
            j += 1
        arr[i, :] = temp_list
        i += 1
    return arr
```

I get this error:

```
arr[i, :] = temp_list  
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 8 to array axis with dimension 4
```

for an input array of:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

one should get a result:

```
0 1 2
4 5 3
8 6 7
```

or for this input:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

this output

```
0 1 2 3
5 6 7 4
10 11 8 9
15 12 13 14
```

Comment: Can you please provide example input and output?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick little function that will do the job.  Essentially, each sub-array is shifted by its index in the parent array.

Setup:

```
l1 = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
l2 = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
l3 = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Function:

```
def spiral(array):
    temp = []
    for i, a in enumerate(array):
        n = i % len(a)
        temp.append(a[n:] + a[:n])
        n += 1
    return temp
```

Output:

```
>>> spiral(l1)
[[0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 3], [8, 6, 7]]

>>> spiral(l2)
[[0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 3], [8, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11], [13, 14, 12], [17, 15, 16]]

>>> spiral(l3)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 4], [10, 11, 8, 9], [15, 12, 13, 14]]
```

#### Edit:

Per OP's comments, function updated to simplify and ensure compatibility with nested lists of differing lengths.

Comment: I do not think this is quite right, logic-wise!
neither applicable  for an array from a different size, I tried it on a 4x4 and got the last row unchanged

Comment: Ok; will have a look.  If there are any requirements (or implementation details) not in the original question, please update accordingly.

Comment: I updated the question again with some more details :)

Comment: Excellent, thanks mate.  Answer updated and now shows compatibility with nested lists of varying lengths.

Comment: this is great, thank you so much!    
 just one more question, your code works fine on Jupyter Notebook  but not in my PyCharm project, there I get     
"   
 temp.append(a[n:] + a[:n])   
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (0,) 
"

Comment: Excellent, glad to help.  Please accept the answer by clicking the tick (check mark) by the answer.  (Common SO practice for accepted answers).  Re: Jupyter vs PyCharm - I’ve tested on Jupyter and Spyder and all is well.  Note these are lists, not numpy arrays; which is what seems to be triggering the error in PyC.

Comment: ... the function can be updated to convert a numpy array to a list using `array.tolist()`.  Then all will be fine.  This function was intentionally written to use builtins only, and no external libs, such as `numpy`; (as shown in your example).